How to Anchor SwiftUI Bottom Sheet to the Screen Bottom Inside a ScrollView?
I am developing an app using SwiftUI and facing an issue with positioning a custom bottom sheet within a view that contains a ScrollView. The bottom sheet is supposed to anchor to the bottom of the screen, but it currently anchors to the bottom of the ScrollView content, causing it to appear only after scrolling down to the end of the ScrollView.
Here is the code for the bottom sheet:
struct BottomSheetViewModal<Content: View>: View {
    @Binding var isPresented: Bool
    let content: () -> Content

    var body: some View {
        ZStack(alignment: .bottom) {
            if isPresented {
                Color.black.opacity(0.3)
                    .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
                    .onTapGesture {
                        isPresented = false
                    }

                content()
                    .background(Color.white)
                    .cornerRadius(16, corners: [.topLeft, .topRight])
                    .padding(.bottom,5)
                    .ignoresSafeArea(.all)
            }
        }
    }
}

extension View {
    func BottomSheetView<Content: View>(
        isPresented: Binding<Bool>,
        @ViewBuilder content: @escaping () -> Content
    ) -> some View {
        ZStack {
            self
            BottomSheetViewModal(isPresented: isPresented, content: content)
        }
    }
}


The BottomSheetViewModal is nested inside a ScrollView which results in the sheet's position being at the bottom of the scrollable content rather than the screen. Because of this, users must scroll to the bottom of the scroll view to see the full bottom sheet.
How can I anchor the BottomSheetViewModal to the bottom of the screen instead of to the bottom of the ScrollView content in SwiftUI? Is there a better way to layer the views or a different approach to positioning the bottom sheet so that it is always visible at the bottom of the screen, regardless of the ScrollView's content size?
Similar to the css effect of
position:fixed;
bottom:0;

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Can you show a [mre]? You don't even have a ScrollView in the code you showed.

This is a custom sheet, right? Why don't you want to use a real .sheet?

I've found that the issue occurs when the custom sheet is nested inside a ScrollView, which causes it to anchor to the bottom of the scrollable content instead of the bottom of the screen. By moving the custom sheet to be at the same hierarchical level as the ScrollView, rather than inside it, the sheet now correctly positions itself at the bottom of the screen.
This adjustment ensures that the sheet does not move with the ScrollView content and is always visible at the screen's bottom, regardless of the scroll position.
Thanks reply! @BenzyNeez

I encountered an issue where my custom bottom sheet was not anchoring to the bottom of the screen but to the bottom of the scrollable content within a ScrollView. After some experimentation, I found that the root of the problem was the hierarchical placement of the bottom sheet relative to the ScrollView.
Here's the solution that worked for me:
Problem: When the custom bottom sheet is nested inside a ScrollView, it anchors to the bottom of the scrollable content.
Solution: By moving the custom bottom sheet to the same hierarchical level as the ScrollView, the sheet now correctly positions itself at the bottom of the screen, independent of the scrollable content.
Here's the code that demonstrates the correct structure:
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var isSheetPresented = false

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            ScrollView {
                // Your scrollable content here
                VStack {
                    ForEach(0..<100) { index in
                        Text("Item \(index)")
                            .padding()
                    }
                }
            }

            // Bottom sheet is placed outside the ScrollView but within the same ZStack
            if isSheetPresented {
                BottomSheetView()
                    .background(Color.white)
                    .cornerRadius(20)
                    .shadow(radius: 10)
                    .frame(height: 300)
                    .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
            }
        }
        .onTapGesture {
            isSheetPresented.toggle()
        }
    }
}

struct BottomSheetView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("This is the bottom sheet content")
                .padding()
        }
    }
}

